# Rank in powerpivot

Tags: powerpivot

In Powerpivot, I have a problem in ranking in Table 1, based on Sales and Year. I want to have the result like that:

```
Year     Store      Sales       **Rank**
2013      A         200         3
2013      B         250         2
2013      C         300         1
2014      A         350         2
2014      B         300         3
2014      C         400         1
```

Which rank function could I use to have this rank result?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Tran,

Probably the smartest way to go is to use the 'X' functions. They can be a bit tricky and non intuitive, yet are extremely powerful.

First, create a simple measure to calculate the total sales:

```
TotalSales:=SUM(Stores[Sales])
```

Then, use this formula below to calculate the rank (per store per year):

```
Rank:=RANKX(ALL(Stores[Store]), [TotalSales])
```

That should do what you are looking for. Once those two measures are ready, create a new powerpivot table, dray *Year* and *Store* onto rows pane and add required values.

[*ALL* function](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/680.powerpivot-dax-filter-functions.aspx#all) overwrites the applied rows filter  and thus allows to calculate rank per year.

The result should look like this:

[image]

Hope this helps.